# Return dataframe subset based on a list of boolean values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to slice a dataframe based on list of values, how would I go about this?

Say I have an expression or a list `l = [0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]`

How to return those rows in a dataframe, `df`, when the corresponding value in the expression/list is 1? In this example, I would include rows where index is 1, 4, 5, and 9.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is something to consider when you have received valuable answers.

Comment: This is called **Boolean Indexing**. See [Selection : Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#selection) in the tutorial 10 Minutes to pandas". However usually the boolean indexing expression is not a plain Python list, but something generated from some expression involving the dataframe column(s) e.g. `df[df['Date'] >= start_date and df['Age'] > 18]`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use masking here:

```
df[np.array([0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],dtype=bool)]
```

So we construct a boolean array with true and false. Every place where the array is True is a row we select.

Mind that we do *not* filter inplace. In order to retrieve the result, you have to assign the result to an (optionally different) variable:

```
df2 = df[np.array([0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1],dtype=bool)]
```

Answer (score 13):

Convert the list to a boolean array and then use boolean indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 3)))

df[np.array(lst).astype(bool)]
Out: 
   0  1  2
1  8  6  3
4  2  7  3
5  7  2  3
9  1  3  4
```

Answer (score 10):

**Setup**
Borrowed @ayhan's setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 3)))
```

**Without `numpy`**
not the fastest, but it holds its own and is definitely the shortest.

```
df[list(map(bool, lst))]

   0  1  2
1  3  5  6
4  6  3  2
5  5  7  6
9  0  0  1
```

---

**Timing**

```
results.div(results.min(1), 0).round(2).pipe(lambda d: d.assign(Best=d.idxmin(1)))

         ayh   wvo   pir   mxu   wen Best
N                                        
1       1.53  1.00  1.02  4.95  2.61  wvo
3       1.06  1.00  1.04  5.46  2.84  wvo
10      1.00  1.00  1.00  4.30  2.73  ayh
30      1.00  1.05  1.24  4.06  3.76  ayh
100     1.16  1.00  1.19  3.90  3.53  wvo
300     1.29  1.00  1.32  2.50  2.38  wvo
1000    1.54  1.00  2.19  2.24  3.85  wvo
3000    1.39  1.00  2.17  1.81  4.55  wvo
10000   1.22  1.00  2.21  1.35  4.36  wvo
30000   1.19  1.00  2.26  1.39  5.36  wvo
100000  1.19  1.00  2.19  1.31  4.82  wvo
```

---

```
fig, (a1, a2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(6, 6))
results.plot(loglog=True, lw=3, ax=a1)
results.div(results.min(1), 0).round(2).plot.bar(logy=True, ax=a2)
fig.tight_layout()
```

[image]

---

**Testing Code**

```
ayh = lambda d, l: d[np.array(l).astype(bool)]
wvo = lambda d, l: d[np.array(l, dtype=bool)]
pir = lambda d, l: d[list(map(bool, l))]
wen = lambda d, l: d.loc[[i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == 1], :]

def mxu(d, l):
    a = np.array(l)
    return d.query('@a != 0')

results = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.Index([1, 3, 10, 30, 100, 300,
                    1000, 3000, 10000, 30000, 100000], name='N'),
    columns='ayh wvo pir mxu wen'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in results.index:
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    l = lst * i
    for j in results.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d, l)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, l, {}'.format(j)
        results.set_value(i, j, timeit(stmt, setp, number=10))
```

Comment: Could you please testing `df.loc[[i for i,x in enumerate(lst) if x == 1],:]`, it should be the slowest one , but just curious how slow it will be ...

Comment: Thank you ~Mine is the worst for no doubt T_T

Answer (score 8):

yet another "creative" approach:

```
In [181]: a = np.array(lst)

In [182]: df.query("index * @a > 0")
Out[182]:
   0  1  2
1  1  5  5
4  0  2  0
5  4  9  9
9  2  2  5
```

or [much better variant from @ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494649/pandas-dataframe-return-subset-based-on-a-list-of-boolean-values/45494910?noredirect=1#comment77951484_45494910):

```
In [183]: df.query("@a != 0")
Out[183]:
   0  1  2
1  1  5  5
4  0  2  0
5  4  9  9
9  2  2  5
```

PS i've also borrowed @Ayhan's setup

Comment: Wouldn't `df.query("@a > 0")` suffice?

Comment: @ayhan, yes, indeed, thank you! That looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Or maybe find the position of 1 in your `list` and slice from the `Dataframe`

```
df.loc[[i for i,x in enumerate(lst) if x == 1],:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecting using a list of Booleans is something [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) does well.

Given

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 2)))
>>> selectors = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Code

```
>>> selected_idxs = list(itertools.compress(df.index, selectors))   # [1, 4, 5, 9]
>>> df.iloc[selected_idxs, :]
   0  1
1  1  9
4  3  4
5  4  1
9  8  9
```